# resizing the image to fit the parent CSS/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html and a CSS file where I set the background of the body tag to `background-image: url(..);`
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=yes">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/coreStyleSheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/animate.css">
    <script src="public/js/coreHomePage.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> </head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light animated fadeInLeft" style="background-color: #C0C0C0 ;">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="lines"></span><span class="lines"></span><span class="lines"></span></button>
        <h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0 move-header">NavBrand</h1>
        <div class="collapse animated fadeInLeft" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url(../../assests/img/back.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

The real issues start when I start resizing the window,the image start resizing well and good when it time for the **image to resize the *height*** there is lot of distortion in the image like some apart of the image move and some stays still. I could show you but I am not able to capture the screen. But when I run in the **JSFIDDLE** it works fine. there is media queries in my code which comes after the body tag.

PS:Using bootstrap4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing the window while preserving the background image properly has always worked for me using this syntax, especially using Bootstrap.

```
html { 
  background: url(../../assests/img/back.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This fixes and centers the background as the window is resized.

Comment: Nice and smooth. Thanks bud :)

Comment: Glad I could help.